# Scale cell according to visibility percentage

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

When a cell is fully visible at the center of the collection view, I want it to appear larger than the cells in the sides.

Currently, I'm utilizing `visibleItemsInvalidationHandler` closure to achieve that effect:

```
section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { (items, offset, environment) in

            items.forEach { item in
                let frame = item.frame
                let rect = CGRect(x: offset.x, y: offset.y, width: environment.container.contentSize.width, height: frame.height)
                let inter = rect.intersection(frame)
                let ratio = (inter.width * inter.height) / (frame.width * frame.height)
                let scale = ratio > 0.8 ? ratio : 0.8
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                    item.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.98, y: scale)
                }
            }
        }
```

However, I still don't get the result I'm aiming for. This is what I get:

[image]

The cells start to flicker when swiped, and when I try to get a cell to the center, the result value from `max(ratio, scale)` is less than what it was before. I want the value of `max(ratio, scale)` to increase, the more the cell is visible on the screen.

Ideally, this is what I'm aiming for:

[image]

MRE:
ViewController, enums and structs:

```
struct BannerEntity: Hashable {
    private let id = UUID()
    let bannerTitle: String
    
    init(bannerTitle: String) {
        self.bannerTitle = bannerTitle
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: BannerEntity,
                    rhs: BannerEntity) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

struct HomePresentationModel {
    var section: HomeSection
    var items: [HomeSectionItem]
}

enum HomeSectionItem: Hashable {
    case banner(BannerEntity)
}

struct HomeSection: Hashable {
    var header: HomeSectionHeader
    let sectionType: HomeSectionType
}

enum HomeSectionType: Int, Hashable {
    case banner
}

enum HomeSectionHeader: Int, Hashable {
    case tappableHeader
    case empty
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: Subviews
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    // MARK: Properties
    private lazy var dataSource = makeDataSource()
    private var sections = [HomePresentationModel(section: .init(header: .empty, sectionType: .banner),
                                                  items: [.banner(.init(bannerTitle: "firstBanner")),
                                                          .banner(.init(bannerTitle: "secondBanner")),
                                                          .banner(.init(bannerTitle: "thirdBanner")),
                                                          .banner(.init(bannerTitle: "fourthBanner"))]
                                                 )]
    
    // MARK: Value Type
    typealias DataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<
        HomeSection,
        HomeSectionItem
    >
    typealias Snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<
        HomeSection,
        HomeSectionItem
    >
    
    // MARK: Viewcycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        configureCollectionView()
        applySnapshot()
    }
    
    // MARK: Helpers
    private func configureCollectionView(){
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.frame,
                                          collectionViewLayout: generateLayout())
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.register(BannerCell.self,
                                forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "BannerCell")
    }
    
    private func generateLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
            [self] (sectionIndex: Int,
                    layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment)
            -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
            let sectionType = HomeSectionType(rawValue: sectionIndex)
            
            guard sectionType == .banner else {return nil}
            return self.generateBannersLayout()
        }
        return layout
    }
    
    func generateBannersLayout() -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                                              heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.9),
                                               heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.28))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize,
                                                       subitems: [item])
        group.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0,
                                                      leading: 0,
                                                      bottom: 0,
                                                      trailing: 0)
        group.interItemSpacing = NSCollectionLayoutSpacing.fixed(0)
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10,
                                                        leading: 0,
                                                        bottom: 10,
                                                        trailing: 0)
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered
        
        section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { (items, offset, environment) in
            
            items.forEach { item in
                let frame = item.frame
                let rect = CGRect(x: offset.x, y: offset.y, width: environment.container.contentSize.width, height: frame.height)
                let inter = rect.intersection(frame)
                let ratio = (inter.width * inter.height) / (frame.width * frame.height)
                let scale = ratio > 0.8 ? ratio : 0.8
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                    item.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.98, y: scale)
                }
            }
        }
        return section
    }
    
    private func makeDataSource() -> DataSource {
        let dataSource = DataSource(
            collectionView: collectionView,
            cellProvider: { (collectionView, indexPath, item) ->
                UICollectionViewCell? in
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
                    withReuseIdentifier: "BannerCell",
                    for: indexPath) as? BannerCell
                return cell
            })
        
        return dataSource
    }
    
    private func applySnapshot() {
        var snapshot = Snapshot()
        snapshot.appendSections(sections.map({$0.section}))
        sections.forEach { section in
            snapshot.appendItems(section.items, toSection: section.section)
        }
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
}
```

BannerCell:

```
import UIKit

class BannerCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    // MARK: Init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupSubviews()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // MARK: Helpers
    private func setupSubviews(){
        backgroundColor = .purple
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick google search for `uicollectionview zoom center cell` finds many examples and discussions. You may want to look at a few of those to see what they're doing differently.

Comment: Almost all of the results are for the standard UICollectionViewFlowLayout, but since I'm using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout, I find it more challenging to achieve the same result. @DonMag

Comment: OK - if you put together a [mre] that we can run and inspect, it will be easier to get help.

Comment: I just did, please check the MRE and let me know if there is anything more I need to provide. @DonMag

Comment: ED. -- good job on the MRE ... it amazes me how many people posting questions here have trouble with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close...

First, no need for the `UIView.animate` block. `.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler` is called for each layout cycle, so it's triggered (effectively) continuously as we scroll the section.

Second, your height scale calculation is not-quite-right...

You're getting the intersection (`CGRect`) of the cell frame with the view frame, so we want the height scale to match the **percentage** of the width of the intersecting rect. Well, in this case, the percentage of the range between `0.8` and `1.0`.

If you change your `.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler` to this, it should be what you're going for -- or at least close enough that you can tweak it to your satisfaction:

```
    section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { (items, offset, environment) in
        items.forEach { item in
            let frame = item.frame
            let rect = CGRect(x: offset.x, y: offset.y, width: environment.container.contentSize.width, height: frame.height)
            let inter = rect.intersection(frame)
            let percent: CGFloat = inter.width / frame.width
            let scale = 0.8 + (0.2 * percent)
            item.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.98, y: scale)
        }
    }
```